# Sequential rendering of elements in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm recently learning vue and making a ranking component.

For it to work properly, I need to display the elements one by one, as in the example:

```
<input type="text">
<label for=""></label>
<input type="text">
<label for=""></label>
<input type="text">
<label for=""></label>
```

But my code obviously draws the inputs first and then the labels:

```
<script setup>
  const stars = [
    { id: "star5", value: 5 },
    { id: "star4.5", value: 4.5 },
    { id: "star4", value: 4 },
    { id: "star3.5", value: 3.5 },
    { id: "star3", value: 3 },
    { id: "star2.5", value: 2.5 },
    { id: "star2", value: 2 },
    { id: "star1.5", value: 1.5 },
    { id: "star1", value: 1 },
    { id: "star0.5", value: 0.5 },
  ];
</script>

<template>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="rating">
      <input
        type="radio"
        v-for="star in stars"
        :key="star.value"
        :id="star.id"
        :name="'rating'"
        :value="star.value"
      />
      <label
        v-for="star in stars"
        :key="star.value"
        :for="star.id"
        :class="[star.value % 1 === 0 ? 'full' : 'half']"
      ></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried to draw the stars in a different way, like this:

```
<div class="center">
    <fieldset class="rating">
      <div v-for="star in stars" :key="star.id">
        <input type="radio" :id="star.id" :name="'rating'" :value="star.value" />
        <label :for="star.id" :class="[star.value % 1 === 0 ? 'full' : 'half']"></label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
```

But in this case, extra halves were added, and the elements did not work as they should.

How can I draw the elements one by one, as I indicated in the example?

Comment: "extra halves were added, and the elements did not work as they should" -- what does this mean? halves of what? added to what? explain what the actual result looks like and how it differs from your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Change so that your label tag wraps the input, and remove the second v-for from input tag is.

Notice where `</label>` tag is located:

```js
    <div class="center">
      <div class="stars">
        <label
          v-for="star in stars"
          :key="star.value"
          :for="star.id"
          :class="star.value % 1 === 0 ? 'full' : 'half'"
        >
          <input
            type="radio"
            :key="star.value"
            :id="star.id"
            :name="'rating'"
            :value="star.value"
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you manage ratings with a radio inputs. I have created a simple implementation keeping in mind your scenario.

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const stars = ref([
    { id: "star5", value: 5 },
    { id: "star4.5", value: 4.5 },
    { id: "star4", value: 4 },
    { id: "star3.5", value: 3.5 },
    { id: "star3", value: 3 },
    { id: "star2.5", value: 2.5 },
    { id: "star2", value: 2 },
    { id: "star1.5", value: 1.5 },
    { id: "star1", value: 1 },
    { id: "star0.5", value: 0.5 },
  ]);
</script>

<template>
  <div class="center">
    <fieldset class="rating">
      <div v-for="star in stars" :key="star.id">
        <input type="range" :id="star.id" :min="0" max="5" :name="'rating'" v-model="star.value" step=".5" />
        <label :for="star.id" :class="star.value % 1 === 0 ? 'full' : 'half'">
        {{star.value % 1 === 0 ? 'full' : 'half'}} - {{star.value}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</template>
```

[Demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Hope this helps